# Drop SQL Server database from powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, database-administration

I have a SQL Server instance on my local computer called `.\SC`. I want to drop a database from that instance using a PowerShell script. I need to login with the `sa` user for my database.

This is the code I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")
$srv = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(".\SC")
$conContext = $srv.ConnectionContext
$conContext.LoginSecure = $FALSE
$conContext.Login = "sa"
$conContext.Password = "MyPlainTextPass"
$srv2 = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($conContext)
$srv2.Databases
```

That last line is supposed to list the databases in my SQL instance... but it gives me this error:

> The following exception occurred while trying to enumerate the
>   collection: "Failed to connect to server .\SC.". At line:1
>   char:1
>   + $srv2.Databases
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionInGetEnumerator

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your SQL logs for failed login attempts? Failing that, store `$error[0]` into a local variable right after running this and get the Exception and InnerException until you reach the root cause.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found a different command to do this.  It was simply:

```
invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance ".\SC" -U "sa" -P "MyPlainTextPass" -Query "Drop database MyDatabase;"
```

Comment: this would fail if database not exists

Comment: @liang
This would also fail if server doesn't exists, or the user doesn't exist, or if the password isn't correct, if there's no SQL Server on the server, if it is run against SQL Server v1.0, or if it would be executed on a machine without powershell, or executed on a commodore 64...

The point of his answer is about fixing the original problem, not about the decoration around the problem.

Answer (score 7):

The only way to make it work for me was to force any other connections to the database to close, through the following command:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $Server @Auth `
    -Query "IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name ='MyDBName') `
                BEGIN `
                    ALTER DATABASE [MyDBName] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; `
                    DROP DATABASE [MyDBName]; `
                END;" `
    -Verbose
```

The backticks (`) are necessary, otherwise this command would have to be inlined

Comment: Thanks - if using Windows authentication, you can remove `@Auth` from the above.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following:

`$sqlserver = '<enter sql server here>'`
`$database = '<enter db name here>'`

```
Try{
    invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$sqlserver" -Query "Drop database $database;"
}Catch{
      Write-Output 'Failed to delete database'
}
```

That way you can turn it in to a function if needed, with variables, and if it fails it tells you but moves on with the rest of the script it is in.

Answer (score 0):

With all the preparation you have, you seem to forget to actually connect to the server. Note that the below example calls `ConnectionContext.Connect()`.

```
$dbServer = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $server
$smoSecurePassword = $Password  | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$dbServer.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = $false
$dbServer.ConnectionContext.set_Login($User)            
$dbServer.ConnectionContext.set_SecurePassword($smoSecurePassword)
$dbServer.ConnectionContext.Connect() 
$db = $dbServer.Databases
```

If you want to check whether your database exists (like liang pointed out), you can change the last line with:

```
$db = $dbServer.Databases[$database]
```

and verify whether `$db` has a value.